# Install Tomcat remotely (on a digital ocean server?)

Tags: java, tomcat, remote-server, digital-ocean

From a Java app, I'd like to programmatically:

1. start a digital ocean server [EDIT: on LINUX debian]
2. install Tomcat on this server [EDIT: this step must be executed remotely, from my Java app]
3. upload an existing war file to the server and deploy it on Tomcat

I have found all details on SO on how to do 1. an 3., but not 2. ?

Comment: what os? copy and extract zip...

Comment: Ok, I don't know how I can do that remotely from my Java app?

Comment: Why do you want to do it from java app? I mean you can install using putty or vnc then can remotly deploy applications. . Is there any specific needs?

Comment: Yes, the need is to use these DO servers as remote workers launched without human supervision, for jobs of varying times and intensities.

Comment: And what are you planning to do if Tomcat is already installed in the remote PC?

Comment: That's a newly launched Digital Ocean Server, nothing installed on it. Instances I launch shutdown and revert back to their initial state when the job is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have `ssh` access to remote server, you can get a remote shell in you java app using [java secure channel lib](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and run appropriate command to install tomcat (may be : `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`). example for ssh connection from java could be found [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html).